# Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$ and $y=0$ about the x-axis.

Tags: integration, volume

The answer for this question is apparently $36\pi$, but I cannot get that answer. I keep getting $18\pi$, and I have a feeling my professor made a mistake on this. Can I get some clarification?

Comment: What are your limits of integration $[0, 3]$ or $[-3,3]$?  That could well be the difference.  You should be in the habit of showing your work, it helps us to give better answers.

Comment: When you do [-3,3] you get 0, the terms cancel eachother out.

Comment: Well, the volume of a sphere with radius $R$ is $\frac{4\pi}{3}R^3$, so if $R=3$ the volume is $36\pi$.

Comment: Ah ok, what I did was I took the integral from [0,3] then solved. After factoring and taking the anti derivative from y=sqrt(y-x^2) , I got 9x - 1/3 *x^3 which gave me 18pi. I thought the radius is found by using the originial equation given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may calculate the volume as follows:

$$\pi \int_{-3}^3 y^2 dx = \pi  \int_{-3}^3 9 - x^2 \; dx = \pi \left[ 9x - \frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-3}^3 = \pi \left[ 27 - 9 +27 - 9\right] = 36 \pi$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use symmetry to simplify the integral, i.e. when you have

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x) \ dx$$ you can rewrite it as $$2 \int_{0}^a f(x) \ dx.$$

**Note:** randomgirl is correct.  I had mistakenly used the shell method (which is $\pi \int_a^{b} x f(x) \ dx$) rather than the disk method (which is $\pi \int_a^{b} f(x)^2 \ dx$).  Sorry about that!

Comment: Think you put an extra x in it.

Comment: Oops and squaring the radius

Comment: Thanks, randomgirl!  I got the two revolution methods mixed up - the disk method is the proper one.